# How they deduce that $\det A=1$ just from the first coefficient and minor

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, translation-request

[image]

[image]

I found solution of exercise that said show that A is rotation to do that we have to compute det A=1 but they found it directly

Is there any relationship between the first coefficient and minor to say directly without complete computing that $\det A=1$

- **how they deduce that det A=1 just from the first coeffcient and minor**

Comment: This appears to be a special case that relies on some sort of symmetry in the cofactor expansions along the top ow or left column. But I'm not sure how to explain it concretely.

Comment: just try please

Comment: How is the $A$ matrix whose determinant you're speaking about related to the $M$ defined in the first displayed formula?

Comment: its just typo M=A

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is having you try forming the product $A^TA$ and finding that it equals the identity. Therefore, $A^T = A^{-1}$.

Now you can use the equation given, where
$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} C^T = A^T $$
Consider the first element, so
$$ \frac{1}{\det A} C_{11} = A_{11} = \frac{8}{9}$$
Now, $C_{11} = 72/9^2$, so $\det A = \frac{8}{9} \frac{9^2}{72} = 1 $.

Comment: is that hold for any $1\leq i \leq n$  $$\frac{1}{\det A} C_{ii} = A_{ii} $$

Comment: It should hold for any element, not just the diagonal.

Comment: for example:  $$\frac{1}{\det A} C_{ij} = A_{kl}$$

Comment: No, obviously this is only true for corresponding elements. In your equation, you must have $i=k$, and $j=l$.

Answer (score 1):

$DetA = 1$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a matrix being a rotation. To be a rotation $A^T = A^{-1}$ (and here we include reflections composed with rotations, ie $detA = \pm 1$).

Comment: My question wans't about rotation but it was about how they deduce that det A=1 just from the first coeffcient and minor